# Why am I getting this Parse Issue in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm currently learning Objective-C and app development, but I'm also using a canned framework (buzztouch) to develop simple apps. Currently, I'm getting this Parse Issue:

'theTitle' used as the name of the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

Here's the line of code:

```
-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)theTitle:(NSString *)theMessage:(int)alertTag;
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I avoid this in the future? Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm just trying to learn how all of this works.

Comment: Why the down votes? Seems like a legitimate question +1.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the two:

Your code:

```
-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)theTitle:(NSString *)theMessage:(int)alertTag;
```

Now, look at this:

```
-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)theTitle theMessage:(NSString *)theMessage alertTag:(int)alertTag;
```

The problem is in the way you have declared your method:

Here is some detailed information on declaring your methods: [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/). Take a look at the section titled **Methods and Messaging**.

Comment: Another way to look at this is the name of the original method is `showAlert:::`.

Comment: @user2052639: Remember to mark the question as 'Answered' if in fact it helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I find it useful to compare Objective C methods to C++ or C# style methods.

in C#

```
public int Add(int number1, int number2) { 
     return number1 + number2;
}
```

in Objective C

```
- (int)add:(int)number1 toNumber:(int)number2 {
    return number1 + number2
}
```